# Deciding Column Type before creating.

Tags: column, managed-metadata

Does it make sense to create a Managed Metadata column if it will always contain same information? "Year" and "PublisherName" for a given document library will always be the same. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Using Managed Metadata makes sense if:

- The information is hierarchical
- The choices needs to be shared across site collections and maintained by endusers

If the information is flat and you only need to maintain the choices inside a single site collection then I'd not use Managed Metadata, but instead use either choice or lookup columns.